# Speech to Text in XCODE Example

Tags: xcode, speech-to-text

I've been looking a sample code in the internet on how to create an xcode app that will convert voice/speech to text.

Hopefully guys you could lead me to a link on how to do this, I am a newbie in xcode, would appreciate if the link will be a little bit detailed in explanation or in code.

Thanks Guys and Rest of all stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is not the kind of question you are supposed to ask. You should pose a problem and give examples of what you have done so far with the problem, rather than just asking for material.
What you should search for is OpenEars. It's a speech to text library with tutorials on the website. It also does text to speech. However, it has limitations so be sure to read all its documentation and advice first.